# Генерация никогда не повторяющейся последовательности

Tags: golang, алгоритм, java, c++, ubuntu

Мне надо найти алгоритм генерации никогда не повторяющейся последовательности. В последовательность могут входить цифры и буквы (нельзя включать нечитаемые символы). Нужно примерно то же, что и в генерации GUID в для COM-объектов. Если кто знает популярные алгоритмы/библиотеки, прошу поделиться советом.

Comment: А сам [UUID](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) почему не подходит?

Comment: Совет в лоб: md5 от текущей даты + MAC сетевой карты (или SN другого железа).

Comment: другие постеснялись в этом вам признатся но я не люблю врать. нет такого алгоритма. чтоб всегда была случайная последовательность. для последовательности любой длинны количество вариантов ограниченное. логично предположить что для того чтоб ваша последовательность никогда не повторялась надо ее длину каждый раз увиличивать хотя бы на 1 бит. 

как вам уже предлагали md5 от даты + 1 бит/байт как вам удобнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как верно подметил [@VioLet](/users/852/violet), можно использовать UUID. Не доконца разобрался, будит ли он уникальным всегда или нет, но нашел реализацию v4 на Go. Код:

```
func NewUUID() []byte {
    uuid := make([]byte, 16)

    _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, uuid)

    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var version byte = 4 << 4
    var variant byte = 2 << 4

    uuid[6] = version | (uuid[6] & 15)
    uuid[8] = variant | (uuid[8] & 15)

    return uuid
```

}

Comment: Учитывая кол-во ключей = 3.4 × 10^38, можно считать каждый новый ключ уникальным. Ну или, дабы прям совсем исключить возможность повторения, можно, как сказал @fogbit, добавлять к нему еще и timestamp (или строку текущего времени).

Answer (score 1):

Весь вопрос упирается в степень достоверности уникальности кода. Если это не сильно принципиально (ну скажем устраивает вероятность появления повторяющегося кода порядка 10 в минус 6-7) - то вполне нормально тупо брать текущее время + случайный символ и хэш ключ от этого значения. В псевдокоде я бы написал так:

```
return hash(System.currentTimeMillis() & random());
```

Если требуется железобетонная уверенность то нужен генератор спецом. В Java для этого существует удобный пакет [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Непериодическую последовательность дают коэффициенты непрерывной (цепной) дроби в разложении корня четвёртой степени из числа. Ибо любая периодическая цепная дробь соответствует квадратичной иррациональности.
Суть алгоритма проста.
1. Задумать натуральное число N, не являющееся квадратом натурального числа.
2. Вычислить с большой точностью десятичную дробь sqrt(sqrt(N)) (алгоритм точного извлечения квадратного корня известен).
3. Преобразование полученной дроби в непрерывную (цепную) дробь даёт непериодическую последовательность натуральных чисел.

Comment: Можете посоветовать хорошие статьи по цепным дробям? Все, что пытался читать до этого, было невыносимо скучно и блевотно, хотя я, в общем-то, люблю прикладную алгебру и теорию чисел. Что-нибудь ориентированное на атаку Винера. Увлекательно пишут те, кому важна практика. Например, Крис Касперски писал про реализацию кодов Рида--Соломона. Пацаны с античата интересно писали про эллиптические кривые. А теоретики пишут блевотно.

Comment: @typemoon А рискните-ка скачать книжку И.М. Виноградова http://mathscinet.ru/files/VinogradovIM.pdf, академики умели и рассказывать, и уголком делить :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, например, такой забавный алгоритм для генерации бесконечной последовательности строк без повторений. (Поскольку указан тэг [алгоритм](/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) и несколько языков, пишу на C#.)

```
IEnumerable<string> GenerateUniqueStrings()
{
    yield return "";
    foreach (string s in GenerateUniqueStrings())
    {
        for (var c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            yield return s + c;
    }
}
```

<sub>(Честно украдено из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396731/276994), который мне очень нравится.)</sub>